# Force a derived class without implementing pure virtuals again

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-design

I have defined an interface class `A` which defines some basic functions. In my implementation I have a base class `A0` which implements this interface and from this base class I have derived several other classes in a hierarchy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class IContainer
{
public:
    IContainer() {};
    virtual ~IContainer() {};

    virtual void loadDefaults() = 0;
    virtual void storeDefaults() = 0;

    virtual bool open() = 0;
    virtual bool close() = 0;
};

class IContainerReader
{
public:
    IContainerReader() {};
    virtual ~IContainerReader() {};

    virtual bool read() = 0;
};

class IContainerWriter
{
public:
    IContainerWriter() {};
    virtual ~IContainerWriter() {};

    virtual bool write() = 0;
};

class ContainerBase : public IContainer
{
public:
    ContainerBase() {}
    virtual ~ContainerBase() {}

    void loadDefaults() {}
    void storeDefaults() {}
};

class CSVBase : public ContainerBase
{
public:
    CSVBase() {}
    virtual ~CSVBase() {}

    void setFilename() {}
    bool open() { return true; }
    bool close() { return true; }
};


class CSVReader : public CSVBase, public IContainerReader
{
public:
    CSVReader() {}
    virtual ~CSVReader() {}

    bool read() { return true; }
};

class CSVWriter : public CSVBase, public IContainerWriter
{
public:
    CSVWriter() {}
    virtual ~CSVWriter() {}

    bool write() { return true; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CSVReader r;
    CSVWriter w;
    IContainerReader *ir = &r;
    IContainerWriter *iw = &w;

    ir->open();
    iw->open();

    ir->read();
    iw->write();

    ir->close();
    iw->close();

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see I defined a `IContainerReader` and a `IContainerWriter` class which defines special functions only relevant to the respective implementation.

But now I have a problem, because I want to be sure that a Reader or a writer always has the container base as well. So the logical solution would be to derive `IContainerReader/-Writer` from `IContainer`. But when I do this, thge compiler complains, because it expects that now a `Reader/Writer` object implements again the base functions as well, which are already defined via the base class. But if I let `IContainerReader` not derive from `IContainer` a pointer to one of those objects is not guruanteed to have the `IContainer` functionality as well.

If I try to compile it like this I get errors, because `IContainerReader` is not a `IContainer`

```
||=== Build: Debug in CPPMingW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|83|error: 'class IContainerReader' has no member named 'open'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|84|error: 'class IContainerWriter' has no member named 'open'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|89|error: 'class IContainerReader' has no member named 'close'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|90|error: 'class IContainerWriter' has no member named 'close'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s)) ===|
```

However, if I derive `IContainerReader` from `IContainer` as it should be, I get the following errors:

```
||=== Build: Debug in CPPMingW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|78|error: cannot declare variable 'r' to be of abstract type 'CSVReader'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|58|note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'CSVReader':|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|11|note:     virtual void IContainer::loadDefaults()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|12|note:     virtual void IContainer::storeDefaults()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|14|note:     virtual bool IContainer::open()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|15|note:     virtual bool IContainer::close()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|79|error: cannot declare variable 'w' to be of abstract type 'CSVWriter'|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|67|note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'CSVWriter':|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|11|note:     virtual void IContainer::loadDefaults()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|12|note:     virtual void IContainer::storeDefaults()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|14|note:     virtual bool IContainer::open()|
D:\src\c\Tests\CPPMingW\main.cpp|15|note:     virtual bool IContainer::close()|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 6 second(s)) ===|
```

So the compiler expects me to reiplment all the functions from the base classes in the derived class as well.

So is there a solution to this, without having to define all these functions in the Reader/Writer class again? Of course I could implement dummies which just go down to the base class, but I consider this a bit clumsy and unneccessary overhead and I hope that there may be a better solution for this.

Comment: For me is the multi inherentance a red flag for me. Your CSVReader is a IContainerReader **and** a CSVContainer? I would expect that the CSVReader reads a (csv) file, parses it, and outputs a CSVContainer object.

Comment: This is a short sample to demonstrate the problem. The project is much larger, but obviously I can't post thousands of lines. Thats the point of a SSCE.

Comment: The comment I have is about how the code is being used, I don't need more code ;) Related to: "because I want to be sure that a Reader or a writer always has the container base as well."

Comment: Maybe the word "Container" is here missleading, because in my context, the container refers to an object which can hold (columnar) data. CSV is only one example, there are other containers as well and I don't want to reimplement the common functionality again and again. I did this projec tin Java already, and there a method is found even if it is in a base class. Apparently this is not the case in C++, so I wonder if there is a more elegant way. I can let `Reader/Writer` return a base object, which would be my prefered solution if there is no alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got it right. You have a kind of diamond problem. You inherit from the `IContainer` via two paths .

Normally in such cases you would have two instances of `IContainer` created per one instance of `CSVReader`, and the calls to `IContainer` methods would be ambiguous. In your case the path through `IContainerReader` does not have defined the mentioned functions. [Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) makes that only one instance is created.

Inheritance from `IContainer` should be declared as `virtual`. [Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) makes that every derivation from a class "will get combined together" (sorry for not very technical terms but this is how I understand it in *simple english*). In your case, only one copy of `IContainer` for both paths will be created, and the `vtable`s will get filled from both paths.

This code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class IContainer
{
public:
    IContainer() {};
    virtual ~IContainer() {};

    virtual void loadDefaults() = 0;
    virtual void storeDefaults() = 0;

    virtual bool open() = 0;
    virtual bool close() = 0;
};

class IContainerReader : virtual public IContainer
{
public:
    IContainerReader() {};
    virtual ~IContainerReader() {};

    virtual bool read() = 0;
};

class IContainerWriter : virtual public IContainer
{
public:
    IContainerWriter() {};
    virtual ~IContainerWriter() {};

    virtual bool write() = 0;
};

class ContainerBase : virtual public IContainer
{
public:
    ContainerBase() {}
    virtual ~ContainerBase() {}

    void loadDefaults() {}
    void storeDefaults() {}
};

class CSVBase : public ContainerBase
{
public:
    CSVBase() {}
    virtual ~CSVBase() {}

    void setFilename() {}
    bool open() { return true; }
    bool close() { return true; }
};


class CSVReader : public CSVBase, public IContainerReader
{
public:
    CSVReader() {}
    virtual ~CSVReader() {}

    bool read() { return true; }
};

class CSVWriter : public CSVBase, public IContainerWriter
{
public:
    CSVWriter() {}
    virtual ~CSVWriter() {}

    bool write() { return true; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CSVReader r;
    CSVWriter w;
    IContainerReader *ir = &r;
    IContainerWriter *iw = &w;

    ir->open();
    iw->open();

    ir->read();
    iw->write();

    ir->close();
    iw->close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thx! I didn't know that a derivation also can be virtual :)